# Assigning the counter in a loop to a variable doesn't retain it's current value

Tags: javascript

I do not understand the behavior below.

I am expecting the script below to do the following:

1. Get all elements with the class 'button'
2. For each element with button, assign an onclick event
3. When the user clicks a button, there's an alert with the current value of `i` when the onclick was assigned.

So I would expect clicking "Button 1" would alert "I am button 1".

Instead all 3 buttons alert "I am button 3". It looks like the `i` counter's value isn't be retained.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="button">Button 0</p>
        <p class="button">Button 1</p>
        <p class="button">Button 2</p>
        <script>
            var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
            for (var i=0 ; i < buttons.length ; i++){
                buttons[i].onclick = function(){
                    alert("I am button " + i);
                };
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why does this happen? How can I achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: You need to form a closure!

Comment: @ClydeLobo that question *does* answer my question, but prior to asking this question, I wouldn't have thought to even search for closures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It is called [**Closures**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work). It captures the variable `i` and because `i` is not deleted after the loop, it calls the event handlers with the current value of `i`. So you need a local variable, which you can get by executing function. So I create a function, pass a variable `i` to him, and in the function scope I have a variable, local to the function, `param`, which is new per iteration.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="button">Button 0</p>
        <p class="button">Button 1</p>
        <p class="button">Button 2</p>
        <script>
            var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
            for (var i=0 ; i < buttons.length ; i++){
                buttons[i].onclick = (function(param){
                    return function(){
                    alert("I am button " + param);
                      };
                })(i);
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or you can use `ES6 feature let`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title>Test</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p class="button">Button 0</p>
            <p class="button">Button 1</p>
            <p class="button">Button 2</p>
            <script>
                var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
                for (let i = 0 ; i < buttons.length ; i++){
                    buttons[i].onclick = function(){
                        alert("I am button " + i);
                     }
                }

            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Wow. This got me because (1) I didn't understand closures or their purpose and (2) assumed that `i` no longer existed once the for loop was concluded.

Answer (score 0):

the callback `button.onclick` is a closure, it has in the stack the reference to the i variable that is equal to the last value from the loop